# Long-generating Bash prompt wraps incorrectly when I start typing

Tags: bash, prompt

I have a Bash prompt that takes a while (~100-200ms) to generate, because it includes Git working tree status that takes some time to compute. Sometimes I start typing a command before it appears, but then the command wraps incorrectly.

Here is what I see in the terminal:

```
# I start typing:
some command...

# then the prompt appears:
some command...username [branch*] some/directory $ some command...

# then I type some more, causing the command to wrap:
some command...username [branch*] some/directory $ some command...wra
pping text 1

# and when I continue typing, the text overwrites the second line:
some command...username [branch*] some/directory $ some command...wra
wrapping text 2
```

Any idea how to prevent this?

Here is how my Bash prompt is set up:

```
# in .bashrc:
PROMPT_COMMAND="PS1=\`/home/username/my-prompt.sh\`"

# in /home/username/my-prompt.sh:
$PROMPT=...
$PROMPT+=...
echo -ne $PROMPT
```

I believe I set up all my `\[` and `\]`s correctly inside $PROMPT. The issue appears only when I start typing before the prompt appears, and my command wraps.

Comment: You could use a `\r` at the beginning of the prompt (inside the `\[` `\]` part) to make the prompt always start at the beginning of the line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may work to disable terminal output while the prompt is generated:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND="PS1=\$(stty -echo)\`/home/username/my-prompt.sh\`\$(stty echo)"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to bring your terminal to sane mode(kidding) using

```
stty sane  # I hope it'll help and bring back the working of default prompt.
```

Comment: this may not be a good idea - that is not necessarily the terminal's default, and much of the effects dont apply to `readline` anyway because it will just reset it to raw mode and handle the rest on its own. `stty sane` should probably be considered a last ditch - not a default.

Comment: @mikeserv-Might be!

Comment: very good point.